# calculates the sum of my sales for the past week

Tags: powerbi, dax

Calculate the sum of my sales from last week in Power BI (DAX).

Example: From Filter, If I have select a date that belongs to the 5th week of March then the result must be the sum of the sales of the 4th week of March.

I have tried this code but it doesn't return the desired result:

```
'THSalesp W-1 = CALCULATE(SUM(FACT_Production[THSales]); WEEKNUM(DIM_Time[CalDate])-(1))'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem I was forced to modify my fact table and the time dimension by adding columns of concatenation of the year and the week number.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
THSalesp W-1 = CALCULATE(SUM(FACT_Production[THSales])
                        ,WEEKNUM(SELECTEDVALUE("YOUR FILTER DATE"))-1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it didn't work so I opted for another solution, I made changes in my fact table and my time dimension.